# Migration into devops azure services "Custom type 'Bug' added a new field"

Tags: azure-devops, devops, data-migration

we are going to migrate an old project from DevOps Server 2020 1.2 into DevOps Azure Services (cloud). I'm getting the following exceptions and I know that I can remove the custom fields, but I would like to keep those including old values (they are needed).
How can I proceed with those errors?

```
[Info   @11:50:31.525] === Found 102 error(s) when compared against process TFS 2019 Update 1 Agile ===
[Error  @11:50:31.525] Rules for field 'Microsoft.VSTS.Build.FoundIn' do not match at level 'Bug'.
[Error  @11:50:31.525] Custom type 'Bug' added a new field 'Microsoft.VSTS.Common.BacklogPriority'.
[Error  @11:50:31.525] Custom type 'Bug' added a new field 'Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.Effort'.
[Error  @11:50:31.525] Custom type 'Bug' added a new field 'Microsoft.VSTS.Common.AcceptanceCriteria'.
[Error  @11:50:31.525] Custom type 'Bug' added a new field 'WS.Technologien'.
[Error  @11:50:31.525] Custom type 'Bug' added a new field 'WS.Produkt'.
[Error  @11:50:31.525] Custom type 'Bug' added a new field 'WS.Sprache'.
[Error  @11:50:31.525] Custom type 'Bug' added a new field 'WS.Haeufigkeit'.
[Error  @11:50:31.525] Custom type 'Bug' added a new field 'WS.Buildnumber'.
[Error  @11:50:31.525] Custom type 'Bug' added a new field 'WS.CobraSid'.
[Error  @11:50:31.525] Custom type 'Bug' added a new field 'WS.CobraErsteller'.
[Error  @11:50:31.525] Custom type 'Bug' added a new field 'WS.VersionFound'.
[Error  @11:50:31.525] Custom type 'Bug' added a new field 'WS.VersionFixed'.
[Error  @11:50:31.525] Custom type 'Bug' added a new field 'WS.CustomersCount'.
[Error  @11:50:31.525] Custom type 'Bug' added a new field 'Microsoft.VSTS.Common.OrderSupp'.
[Error  @11:50:31.525] Custom type 'Bug' added a new field 'WS.Group'.
[Error  @11:50:31.525] Custom type 'Bug' added a new field 'WS.AllCustomersAffected'.
[Error  @11:50:31.525] Custom type 'Bug' added a new field 'WS.WorkaroundAvailable'.
[Error  @11:50:31.525] Custom type 'Bug' added a new state definition 'Done'.
[Error  @11:50:31.525] Custom type 'Bug' added a new state definition 'Approved'.
[Error  @11:50:31.525] Custom type 'Bug' added a new state definition 'Committed'.
[Error  @11:50:31.525] Custom type 'Bug' added a new state definition 'Rejected'.
[Error  @11:50:31.525] Custom type 'Bug' added a new state definition 'Removed'.
[Error  @11:50:31.525] Custom type 'Bug' added a new state transition reason '->New/New defect reported'.
[Error  @11:50:31.525] Custom type 'Bug' added a new state transition 'New->Done'.
[Error  @11:50:31.525] Custom type 'Bug' added a new state transition 'Approved->Done'.
[Error  @11:50:31.525] Custom type 'Bug' added a new state transition 'Committed->Done'.
[Error  @11:50:31.525] Custom type 'Bug' added a new state transition 'New->Removed'.
[Error  @11:50:31.525] Custom type 'Bug' added a new state transition 'Approved->Removed'.
[Error  @11:50:31.525] Custom type 'Bug' added a new state transition 'Done->New'.
[Error  @11:50:31.525] Custom type 'Bug' added a new state transition 'Removed->New'.
[Error  @11:50:31.525] Custom type 'Bug' added a new state transition 'Approved->New'.
[Error  @11:50:31.525] Custom type 'Bug' added a new state transition 'Committed->New'.
[Error  @11:50:31.525] Custom type 'Bug' added a new state transition 'Done->Approved'.
[Error  @11:50:31.525] Custom type 'Bug' added a new state transition 'New->Approved'.
[Error  @11:50:31.525] Custom type 'Bug' added a new state transition 'Committed->Approved'.
[Error  @11:50:31.525] Custom type 'Bug' added a new state transition 'Done->Committed'.
[Error  @11:50:31.525] Custom type 'Bug' added a new state transition 'New->Committed'.
[Error  @11:50:31.525] Custom type 'Bug' added a new state transition 'Approved->Committed'.
[Error  @11:50:31.525] Custom type 'Bug' added a new state transition 'Rejected->New'.
[Error  @11:50:31.525] Custom type 'Bug' added a new state transition 'Committed->Rejected'.
[Error  @11:50:31.525] Custom type 'Bug' added a new state transition 'Approved->Rejected'.
[Error  @11:50:31.525] Custom type 'Epic' added a new field 'Microsoft.VSTS.Common.BacklogPriority'.
[Error  @11:50:31.525] Custom type 'Epic' added a new field 'Microsoft.VSTS.Common.AcceptanceCriteria'.
[Error  @11:50:31.525] Custom type 'Epic' added a new state definition 'Done'.
[Error  @11:50:31.525] Custom type 'Epic' added a new state definition 'In Progress'.
[Error  @11:50:31.525] Custom type 'Epic' added a new state transition reason '->New/New epic'.
[Error  @11:50:31.525] Custom type 'Epic' added a new state transition 'In Progress->Removed'.
[Error  @11:50:31.525] Custom type 'Epic' added a new state transition 'In Progress->New'.
[Error  @11:50:31.525] Custom type 'Epic' added a new state transition 'Done->New'.
[Error  @11:50:31.525] Custom type 'Epic' added a new state transition 'New->In Progress'.
[Error  @11:50:31.525] Custom type 'Epic' added a new state transition 'Done->In Progress'.
[Error  @11:50:31.525] Custom type 'Epic' added a new state transition 'New->Done'.
[Error  @11:50:31.525] Custom type 'Epic' added a new state transition 'In Progress->Done'.
[Error  @11:50:31.525] Custom type 'Feature' added a new field 'Microsoft.VSTS.Common.BacklogPriority'.
[Error  @11:50:31.525] Custom type 'Feature' added a new field 'Microsoft.VSTS.Common.AcceptanceCriteria'.
[Error  @11:50:31.525] Custom type 'Feature' added a new field 'WS.CustomersCount'.
[Error  @11:50:31.525] Custom type 'Feature' added a new field 'WS.AllCustomersAffected'.
[Error  @11:50:31.525] Custom type 'Feature' added a new field 'WS.WorkaroundAvailable'.
[Error  @11:50:31.525] Custom type 'Feature' added a new state definition 'In Progress'.
[Error  @11:50:31.525] Custom type 'Feature' added a new state definition 'Done'.
[Error  @11:50:31.525] Custom type 'Feature' added a new state definition 'Rejected'.
[Error  @11:50:31.525] Custom type 'Feature' added a new state transition reason '->New/New feature'.
[Error  @11:50:31.525] Custom type 'Feature' added a new state transition 'Done->In Progress'.
[Error  @11:50:31.525] Custom type 'Feature' added a new state transition 'New->In Progress'.
[Error  @11:50:31.525] Custom type 'Feature' added a new state transition 'In Progress->Done'.
[Error  @11:50:31.525] Custom type 'Feature' added a new state transition 'New->Done'.
[Error  @11:50:31.525] Custom type 'Feature' added a new state transition 'In Progress->Removed'.
[Error  @11:50:31.526] Custom type 'Feature' added a new state transition 'In Progress->New'.
[Error  @11:50:31.526] Custom type 'Feature' added a new state transition 'Done->New'.
[Error  @11:50:31.526] Custom type 'Feature' added a new state transition 'New->Rejected'.
[Error  @11:50:31.526] Custom type 'Feature' added a new state transition 'In Progress->Rejected'.
[Error  @11:50:31.526] Rules for field 'Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Activity' do not match at level 'Task'.
[Error  @11:50:31.526] Custom type 'Task' added a new field 'Microsoft.VSTS.Common.BacklogPriority'.
[Error  @11:50:31.526] Custom type 'Task' added a new field 'Microsoft.VSTS.CMMI.Blocked'.
[Error  @11:50:31.526] Custom type 'Task' added rules for field 'Microsoft.VSTS.CMMI.Blocked' at level 'state[Removed]'.
[Error  @11:50:31.526] Custom type 'Task' added a new state definition 'To Do'.
[Error  @11:50:31.526] Custom type 'Task' added a new state definition 'In Progress'.
[Error  @11:50:31.526] Custom type 'Task' added a new state definition 'Done'.
[Error  @11:50:31.526] Custom type 'Task' added a new state definition 'Rejected'.
[Error  @11:50:31.526] Custom type 'Task' added a new state transition '->To Do'.
[Error  @11:50:31.526] Custom type 'Task' added a new state transition 'In Progress->To Do'.
[Error  @11:50:31.526] Custom type 'Task' added a new state transition 'Done->To Do'.
[Error  @11:50:31.526] Custom type 'Task' added a new state transition 'Removed->To Do'.
[Error  @11:50:31.526] Custom type 'Task' added a new state transition 'To Do->In Progress'.
[Error  @11:50:31.526] Custom type 'Task' added a new state transition 'Done->In Progress'.
[Error  @11:50:31.526] Custom type 'Task' added a new state transition 'To Do->Done'.
[Error  @11:50:31.526] Custom type 'Task' added a new state transition 'In Progress->Done'.
[Error  @11:50:31.526] Custom type 'Task' added a new state transition 'To Do->Removed'.
[Error  @11:50:31.526] Custom type 'Task' added a new state transition 'In Progress->Removed'.
[Error  @11:50:31.526] Custom type 'Task' added a new state transition 'Rejected->To Do'.
[Error  @11:50:31.526] Custom type 'Task' added a new state transition 'In Progress->Rejected'.
[Error  @11:50:31.526] Custom type 'Task' added a new state transition 'Rejected->Done'.
[Error  @11:50:31.526] Custom type 'Task' added a new state transition 'To Do->Rejected'.
[Error  @11:50:31.526] Custom type 'Task' added a new state transition 'Rejected->In Progress'.
[Error  @11:50:31.526] Global lists not allowed in work item types. Found in Task.
[Error  @11:50:31.526] Custom process added a new type 'Custom.Impediment'.
[Error  @11:50:31.526] Custom process added a new type 'Custom.ProductBacklogItem'.
[Error  @11:50:31.526] Custom processConfiguration contain additional typeField 'Order:Microsoft.VSTS.Common.BacklogPriority'.
[Error  @11:50:31.526] Custom processConfiguration contain additional typeField 'Effort:Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.Effort'.
[Error  @11:50:31.526] Custom processConfig has a WorkItem Color defined that is not found in system for type: Impediment
[Error  @11:50:31.526] Custom processConfig has a WorkItem Color defined that is not found in system for type: Product Backlog Item
[Info   @11:50:31.526] === End of error(s) when compared against process TFS 2019 Update 1 Agile ===
```

does anyone have any advice for us? In the case of custom state "Rejected" and state transitions, we have a workaround but much more problems we have with custom fields.
Br